# Is android support library part of android framework APIS?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am new to android app development.I don't understand what the android support library is?.Is it included in android framework APIs like API level 17,18 or is it separate API which can be included in projects.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it included in android framework APIs like API level 17,18

No.

> or is it separate API which can be included in projects

Yes.

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html):

> The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs. Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level. This design means that your applications can use the libraries' features and still be compatible with devices running Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up.